# Child Name Servers in a Google Apps Domain

Tags: domain, nameserver

I've got a personal domain which I use for email (weirdfish.net) which was also had the nameservers for all of my other domains (ns1.weirdfish.net etc)

Last week I decided to switch weirdfish.net over to using GAFYD and since my domains have stopped working, I kind of forgot that domain had child name servers all my other domains used!

So basically should it be possible for me to use a domain with Google Apps and it also have child name servers for my other domain?

If I can't get something sorted I'll have to revert my DNS changes so I can't get my sites back up.

More confusing though is the domains are apparently online for some people! Eg one of my sites is http://mooplug.com which doesn't load for me, but is online according to http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/mooplug.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site is offline now:

```
[vitalie@silver ~]$ host mooplug.com 
Host mooplug.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
[vitalie@silver ~]$ host www.mooplug.com 
Host www.mooplug.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

Many users are using Google's nameservers to resolve DNS queries and domain is already cached there, this can be an explanation why they see it online.

```
[vitalie@silver ~]$ host www.mooplug.com 8.8.8.8
Using domain server:
Name: 8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53
Aliases: 

www.mooplug.com is an alias for mooplug.com.
mooplug.com has address 72.232.250.226
mooplug.com mail is handled by 0 mooplug.com.
```

If you have control over your DNS entries at GAFYD, add A records for your nameserves and it will be OK.

See the DNS report here:

http://www.dnsvalidation.com/mooplug.com

Comment: Ah that would explain why some of my sites were working and not others.  I've added the A records now, can you see if MooPlug.com loads for you now, it does for me

Comment: It resolves OK now.